# Count lines of processed data while parsing it

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of lines that have been processed while parsing the incoming data from millions of small files.

Sample data as example, `tab` is the seperator:

```
CLIENT1.test.com    /var    DIR 21213412    user1   root    default 2000-03-04 18:30:59.000000 PROC_MGMT
CLIENT1.test.com    /usr    DIR 212112  user1   root    default 2006-02-11 08:30:00.000000 PROC_MGMT
CLIENT2.test.com    /var/tmp/test.txt   ACTIVE  FILE    4000    sysuser sysuser NA  2001-04-11 03:00:09.000000 DEFAULT
CLIENT3.test.com    /test.out   PASSIVE FILE    4000    atuser  atgroup group   2012-05-04 02:30:59.000000 AUTOMAT
CLIENT4.test.com    /opt    DIR 542016  dbuser  dbgroup Default 2000-03-04 18:30:59.000000 SYSTEM
```

My code currently looks something like this:

```
PATTERN="mssg1|mssg2|mssg3|...|mssgN"
SERVER=my_server_name

find <path> -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | \
xargs -0 awk -v PAT="$PATTERN" '$0!~PAT' | \
awk '{gsub(/\t/",") {print}}' | \
awk -v SRV="$SERVER" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$1=SRV OFS $1;} {if ($4 !~ /DIR/) $4=","$4;} {print}' | \
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if ($9 == "") $9="01/01/1970 00:00:00 AM"; else {gsub("[:-]"," ",$9); $9=strftime("%m/%d%/Y %r", maketime($9))};} {print}' > /tmp/outputFile.log
```

I can count the total number of lines of all the incoming files by running a `for` loop and `wc -l` (which I guess will be quite slow) and put it as `yyyy` number of lines. 
What I'm looking for is to count the number of lines that I've already processed. So that I can show something like

```
echo "Processed xxxx lines out of yyyy lines"
```

where xxxx is divisible by 1000. For e.g.:

```
Processed 1000 lines out of 1000000 lines.
Processed 2000 lines out of 1000000 lines.
Processed 3000 lines out of 1000000 lines.
.........
Processed 1000000 lines out of 1000000 lines.
Done.
```

Can I add a counter to the `awk` statements that I'm using?

My code is `bash` based running on `RHEL 6.7`.

Comment: `awk` already has a counter called `NR`, which stands for the number (index) of a record. In general case, a record will be a line; or in your case, a null-terminated record. Just google for awk+NR and you'd find some examples.

Comment: @Marcos, could you please post sample input and expected sample output in your post in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Revealing your actual Awk commands would probably enable us to refactor the entire flow to just one or two Awk scripts.

Comment: What do you mean with _'What I'm looking for it to count the number of lines that I've already processed`_

Comment: Where's your input data? Without it, it's difficult to infer what you're trying to do. For example, what the heck is `{if ($4 !~ /DIR/) $6=","$6;}`? Are you inserting a column? Also, I will not help you create dates that are not ISO8601.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) program unifies your entire pipeline.

It is possible to give a count of your records, but it is not possible to print the total number of lines unless you know how many lines there are beforehand. You do know how many files there are, so this you can use as a counter.

```
PATTERN="mssg1|mssg2|mssg3|...|mssgN"
SERVER=my_server_name
find <path> -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | \
xargs -0 awk -v PAT="$PATTERN" -v SRV="$SERVER" -v OUT=/tmp/outputFile.log '
      BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
      (FNR==1){f++} 
      # print progress
      (NR%1000==0){ print "Processed "NR" lines and "f-1" files out of "ARGC-2 }
      # skip line matching pattern
      ($0~PAT){next}
      # substitute all tabs, prepend SRV and redefine fields
      # after this point, we inserted a new field before everything
      { gsub(/\t/,","); $0=SRV OFS $0 }
      # redefine $6 which automatically redefines fields
      # after this line, $4 will be an empty field and $5 will be the old $4
      ($4 !~ /DIR/){ $4 = OFS $4 }
      # process field 9
      { if ($9 == "") $9="01/01/1970 00:00:00 AM"
        else { gsub("[-:]"," ",$9); $9=strftime("%m/%d%/Y %r", maketime($9))} }
      # print to output file
      { print $0 > OUT }
      END{ print "Total lines processed: "NR
           print "Total files processed: "f  }'
```

A general recommendation regarding dates: avoid anything that is not sortable, your format "mm/dd/yyyy", when ascii sorted, is not sorted by date while "yyyy-mm-dd" is. Also, AM and PM for time make not a lot of sense.

https://xkcd.com/1179/

If you want to output the status in a status file, you do

```
xargs ... | awk ' ... 
    END{ print "Total lines processed: "NR > "status.txt"
         print "Total files processed: "f  > "status.txt" }'
```

Comment: How do I put the `END{ print "Total lines processed: "NR print "Total files processed: "f  }'` in another file, something like a status file?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'll test this code. Also, just an update... this one -> `($4 !~ /DIR/){ $6 = OFS $6 }` should be -> `($4 !~ /DIR/){ $4 = OFS $4 }`. I've updated my code as well..

Comment: This needs updating -> `{ gsub(/\t/",")` to `{ gsub(/\t/,",")`. Also, what does the NR represent in `(NR%1000==0){ print "Processed "NR" lines and "f-1" files out of "ARGC-2 }` ? and the NR in `print "Total lines processed: "NR`. Because when I run the test, the last output of NR in `print "Processed "NR" lines ` shows value 17000(for 17690 lines), whereas the total number of lines is 23579 in my sample data, this is shown correctly by `print "Total lines processed: "NR`. So why the GAP ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share my sample data...**corporate restrictions**.

Anyways, I can provide some other info...
First I thought, it might the number of lines ignored by awk based on my Pattern, but 
| 1) No. of lines ignored by Pattern match `($0~PAT){next}` is `18840`.
| 2) No. of lines left after that is `4739`.
| 3) If you sum up the number of (1) & (2), it comes to `23579`, which make perfect sense.
| 4) The number `17690` for no. of lines processed doesn't make sense... Just wondering how NR calculates the number of lines processed.

Comment: I removed the `(NR%1000==0)` thing and modified the `{ print "Processed "NR" lines and "f-1" files out of "ARGC-2 }` to `{ print "Processed "NR" lines }` and let it run, the last one showed `Processed 17690 lines` and as for this `{ print "Total lines processed:`, it showed `Total lines processed: 23579`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out (& bearing with my queries). I've marked your solution as the correct answer.

Comment: @Marcos You are welcome, it was my pleasure. As a final thing, let's clean up the comments which are now irrelevant to the answer (as most of it was a discussion and debugging ;-))